# remove SLASH on single_post but KEEP on categories and parent pages

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, redirect, rewrite-rules, wp-redirect

My current permalink structure is  `/%category%/%postname%/`  which produce urls as:
(category_base removed using "FV Top Level Categories" Plugin)

```
category: example.com/class-10/science/    ◀▬ SLASH is GOOD for directories & ↙ parent pages
    page: example.com/legal/

    post: example.com/class-10/science/ch-1-atoms/    ◀▬ but BAD for single_post, ↖ child pages &
    page: example.com/legal/terms/
    page: example.com/about/    ◀▬ standalone pages
```

So, I want to
**keep** TRAILING SLASH "/" on:

- categories and child categories
- parent pages

**remove** TRAILING SLASH "/" on:

- single_posts
- standalone page (who don't have any child pages)
- child pages

**AND "301" Redirect  "/"  version of these ↖ pages to NON  "/"  version pages**

Answer (score 0):

After SO MANY research, I found a Great Simple solution via  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54251892/10403689 (vote this ⬆UP⬆)

Your Permalink Structure should be: `/%category%/%postname%/`

```
function no_post_slash( $string, $type ){
    if($type == 'single')
        $string = untrailingslashit($string);
   return $string;
}
add_filter('user_trailingslashit', 'no_post_slash', 70, 2);
```

BUT this is only working on single_post not pages